# Error given on hyper js terminal after signin up

Tags: database, redirect, registration

I'm very relatively  into web developpment. I am setting up database and signup users. I'm getting an error after I finish registering the user.

[image]

Underneath is the signup code

```
    app.post("/signup", function(req, res){

  User.register({username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, req.body.fName, req.body.lName, function(err, user){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
     res.redirect("/signup");
} else {
  passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
   res.redirect("/homeafterauthentication");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

To see the registered user in RoboT3 database and to redirect me to `"/homeafterauthentication"` page